# Optimising MySql Query with LEFT JOINS

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization

I am trying to get a list of customer who haven't ordered for 6months or more. I have 4 tables which I have used in the query

- accounts (account_id)
- stores (store_id, account_id)
- customers (store_id, customer_id)
- orders (order_id, customer_id, store_id)

The customer and orders table are very big, 3M and 26M rows respectively, so using left joins in my query make the query time extremely long. I believe I have index my tables correctly

here is my query i have used

```
SELECT cus.customer_id, MAX(o.order_date), cus.store_id, s.account_id, store_name
FROM customers cus 
LEFT JOIN stores s ON s.store_id=cus.store_id  
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id=cus.customer_id AND o.store_id=cus.store_id
WHERE account_id=26  AND  
    (SELECT order_id 
        FROM orders o 
        WHERE o.customer_id=cus.customer_id 
        AND  o.store_id=cus.store_id 
        AND o.order_date < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
        ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 0,1) IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY cus.customer_id, cus.client_id;
```

I need to get the last order date and this is the reason why I have joined the **orders** table, however since the customers can have multiple orders it is returning multiple rows of the customer and that is why I have used the group by clause.

If anyone can assist me with my query.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Does it matter whether the customer bought something more recently at a different store_id?  (Ollie and I make different assumptions here.)

Comment: thanks for your response. Customers cannot have multiple store_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this:

```
SELECT  customer_id, MAX(order_date) AS last_order_date
    FROM  orders
    GROUP BY  customer_id
    HAVING  last_order_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

Assuming that gives you the relevant customer_ids, then move on to

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( that-select-as-a-subquery ) AS old
    JOIN other-tables-as-needed  ON USING(customer_id)
```

If necessary, `JOIN` back to orders to get more info.  Do *not* try to get other columns in that subquery.  (That's a "groupwise max" problem.)

Comment: I think I understand your thought process in what you have suggested, I will see by getting all the orders first, then filter the customers

Comment: thanks for your advice, starting with going through all the orders first by finding the old customers and then filtering on from the customers worked well. The query took just over 5mins, now I might look at doing some smarter indexing.

Comment: This composite index would be a good start:  `INDEX(customer_id, order_date)`.

Comment: I have already indexed client_id and order_date, would I create another set of indexes or add customer_id to my already existing index?

Comment: The _ordering_ of the columns in an index matters.  For my first query, _starting_ an index with `customer_id, order_date`, in _that_ order is important.  That is, add another index.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy of using an ordered and limited subquery on your `orders` table is probably responsible for your poor performance.

This subquery will generate a virtual table showing the date of the most recent order for each distinct customer.  (I guess a distinct customer is distinguished by the pair `customer_id, store_id`).

```
                 SELECT MAX(order_date) recent_order_date,
                        customer_id, store_id
                   FROM orders
                  GROUP BY customer_id, store_id
```

Then, you can use that subquery *as if it were a table* in your query.

```
SELECT cus.customer_id, summary.recent_order_date, 
       cus.store_id, s.account_id, store_name
  FROM customers cus 
  JOIN stores s ON s.store_id=cus.store_id 
  JOIN (
              SELECT MAX(order_date) recent_order_date,
                     customer_id, store_id
                FROM orders
               GROUP BY customer_id, store_id
       ) summary  ON summary.customer_id = cus.customer_id
                 AND summary.store_id = s.store_id
 WHERE summary.recent_order_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
   AND store.account_id = 26
```

This approach moves the `GROUP BY` to an inner query, and eliminates the wasteful  `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` query pattern.  The inner query doesn't have to be remade for every row in the outer query.

I don't understand why you used `LEFT JOIN` operations in your query.

And, by the way, most people, when they're new to SQL, don't have great intuition about which indexes are useful and which aren't. So, when asking for help, it's always good to show your indexes.  In the meantime, read this:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: thanks for your detailed response, I will let you know how i go with it.